# Почему std::initializer_list передается не по ссылке

Tags: c++

Например, вот реализация MSVC конструктора у вектора

```
vector(initializer_list<_Ty> _Ilist, const _Alloc& _Al = _Alloc())
        : _Mybase(_Al)
        {   // construct from initializer_list, optional allocator
        _Range_construct_or_tidy(_Ilist.begin(), _Ilist.end(), random_access_iterator_tag{});
        }
```

Почему initializer_list<...> всюду передается как value, а не lvalue, rvalue ссылки?

Comment: Потому что это всего лишь пара указателей или указатель + размер. Копирование самого содержимого не происходит при передаче по значению.

Comment: а если ещё глубже копнуть, то выяснится, что initializer_list - это так называемый "magic type" - то есть, тип, функционал которого полностью или частично реализован внутри компилятора. И если попытаться реализовать его самому, то ничего не выйдет:)